# Datagridview Sorting with manually added columns

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview control bound to a MySQL database column.

While loading the table to datagridview, i am adding one Column and 8 rows to the datagridview. Values to these manually added coluns and rows are also programitically added. All is working fine except the sorting. When i click on any of column header, datagridview sorts according to the bound table and the manually added column becomes blank.

I want a method to sort the datagridview even if it has a manually added column into it.

Please help....

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Try adding the column to the datatable rather than the actual datagridview, and then fill it with values.

Answer (score 0):

Add the columns and the 8 rows to the table, not the gridview, and do databind after that.

```
Dim dt as System.Data.DataTable = fnGetData()
dt.Columns.Add("new column", GetType(String))
'' for 1 to 8
Dim dr as System.Data.DataRow = dt.NewRow()
'' Fill values
'' dr("new column") = "Some Value"
dt.Rows.Add(dr) 
GridView1.Databind()
```

Comment: Thanx for the code buddy but this is not what wanted. My problem is about the sorting. How should i sort if i have a programitically added column ? :(

Comment: Or are u suggesting to add columns to the data table, assign it to datagridview and then sort ?

Comment: @Mahadev Malkar: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. You might want to save and reapply the sort order, if what you're doing is a table editor.